# Hide field in Infopath form based on user Group

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I am Using Infopath 2013 + SharePoint 2016. How can I hide a field in my form based on user group?

Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. Get Current user Login name using InfoPath fields and store it in a first hidden field.
2. Use REST API to query all current user groups.
3. Concat all group names and store them in a hidden field in the form.
4. Then you will be able to create a rule to test if target group exist in the Hidden Field Value.

This took me 1 week to configure last year, Unfortunally, I dont have anymore access to the customer server. Sorry for that.

There is a SOAP Method that doesn't worked for me at that time because of a bug or incompatibility beetween SharePoint 2016 and InfoPath Designer 2013.

If you are using SP 2013 or 2010 please refer to this [link](http://www.windowsbits.com/knowledge-base/check-if-a-user-is-part-of-a-sharepoint-group-in-infopath/).

Let me know if this was helpful for you.

Comment: Thank You ! How to do this "use REST API to query all current_user groups". i tried the steps provided on that website (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36658.using-sharepoint-2013-get-current-user-group-collection-through-rest-api.aspx) but it doesn't show the group.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide fields based on the SharePoint group membership in the InfoPath form. Check if the current user is a member of a group, then hide fields if the current user is not in the group.

In the form, use GetUserProfileByName (SOAP Web service: http://contoso.com/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx) and GetUserCollectionFromGroup (SOAP Web service: http://contoso.com/_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx) methods to check if the current user is in the specific group. If the current user is not a member of the “Hub Group” group, hide sections which the user has not access.

A demo about how to check if a user is a member of a SharePoint group in InfoPath:

[How To: Check if a user is part of a SharePoint group in web based InfoPath form](https://manojssharepointblog.wordpress.com/2015/02/26/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-part-of-a-sharepoint-group-in-web-based-infopath-form/)

An blog about how to use InfoPath data connection to build rules for hiding/disabling fields based on the SharePoint group membership of current user. Though the links are for InfoPath 2010, but should still have some good information.

[Infopath List Form – hide/disable fields based on SharePoint group membership](http://vuppalasanthosh.blogspot.com/2013/03/infopath-list-form-hidedisable-fields.html)

Or we can use JavaScript code to achieve it. Check the article below.

[Showing or hiding form fields based on membership in a SharePoint group](http://spjsblog.com/2012/05/07/showing-or-hiding-form-fields-based-on-membership-in-a-sharepoint-group/)

Comment: Hi , This doesn't work with SharePoint 2016 which is using claims authentication + Infopath 2013. The steps you provided work only with SharePoint 2010 and infopath 2010